# Flutter: This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled

Tags: flutter, dart

Getting error in `MyApp` constructor

```
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

> This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
> Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 2.12.0 or higher, and running 'pub get'.

but sdk is by default set to 2.12.0 already

```
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

This project is created with the latest versions of Flutter and Dart.

Dart version: `2.13.3`

Flutter version: `2.2.2`

Comment: Try running "flutter clean" and then rebuilding.

Comment: maybe your ide is using the older version of flutter

Comment: Migrate to null safety. Here is the [official guide](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide)

Comment: @gegobyte  I have the exact same issue - did you ever solve it?

Comment: @reesaspieces I disabled null safety. This is my sdk version in pubspec.yaml `sdk: ">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"`

Comment: I see, that's unfortunate :/ Thank you for the update.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had to set it to 2.13.0 to make the error go away:

```
sdk: ">=2.13.0 <3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

A few possibilities:

- The file may have overridden the language level. You can set a specific language version for a file by putting a comment right at the top like: `// @dart=2.9`. This will disable null safety for that file. Check for such a comment, and remove to solve the error
- Similarly, if the entrypoint to your app (usually `lib/main.dart`) has an overridden language level, it will apply that to the project. This error occurs when using `flutter run`, but is typically not shown in the IDE during development
- Your IDE may be using a different version of flutter to the version that you used to capture your versions. You can check the location of your flutter install (on Linux-like systems) by running `which flutter` to see where on your `PATH` the executable is. You can then compare this to the version your IDE uses (varies by IDE)

Comment: Yes, I checked main.dart and at the very top there was the dart language version `// @dart=2.9`, I removed it but nothing changes, all the errors are still there.

Answer (score 1):

it is because of your IDE is using older version of flutter so try to upgrade flutter using this command in your terminal

```
flutter upgrade
```

if stills problem occurs try to clean the project by using command in terminal

```
flutter clean
```

if you want to check whether the flutter is installed properly or not you can check this by writing command in your terminal

```
flutter doctor
```

Comment: It says Flutter is already up to date on channel stable. Have already run `flutter clean` multiple times before but to no effect.